# how select with from mutiple table

Tags: php, mysql, select

```
id  friend1 friend2
1   obi      ezenwa
2   obi      obinna
3   obi      ezenwa
```

this is how i select the list of friends from the table above

```
<?php

require("config.inc.php");

if (!empty($_POST)) {
$query = "SELECT users.* FROM users WHERE users.username IN 
(SELECT friend2 FROM friends where friend1=:username
UNION
SELECT
friend1 FROM friends where friend2=:username)";

    $query_params = array(
        ':username' => $_POST['username']
    );


try {
    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();


if ($rows) {
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Post Available!";
    $response["posts"]   = array();

    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $post             = array();

        $post["TAG_NAME"]    = $row["username"];

        array_push($response["posts"], $post);
    }

    echo json_encode($response);


} else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No Post Available!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}

} else {
?>
        <h1>Login</h1> 
        <form action="selectfriends.php" method="post"> 
            Username:<br /> 
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" /> 
            <br /><br /> 

            <input type="submit" value="Login" /> 
        </form> 
        <a href="register.php">Register</a>
    <?php
}

?>
```

it works well i also have a table like this one below called chatt. where messages of users are saved.

```
                              Chatt
      fromm     too       message           time
        obi2    ezenwa  this is me yes  2015-02-08 23:47:31
        obi     ezenwa  ok i can see    2015-02-08 23:47:31
        obi     ezenwa  seems good      2015-02-12 17:44:10
        ezenwa  obi     i agree         2015-02-12 17:49:16
        obi     ezenwa  j man           2015-02-13 14:42:16
        obi     ezenwa  j man           2015-02-13 14:43:28
        obi2    ezenwa  this is cool    2015-02-13 14:58:28
```

i would like to display the last message between the username that has been enter and all his friends which contained in $row["username"] ...i just want the users list of friends and the last message between them just like blackberry messenger and WhatsApp ....

Comment: So the question is how to print the columns in a different order than they were returned by the query?  Well, that's easy. Each row is returned to you as an array.....so use the array indexes to print in whatever order you want.

Comment: I don't want to stray from the question, but I really think you should rethink your DB design.  You should not store from/to on messages as text, use foreign keys and join the table.  Your going to end up with a TON of redundant data otherwise.